# Kendo ui grid inline and popup mixed and template on popup

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I just saw this [link](https://onabai.wordpress.com/2014/08/28/kendoui-grid-popup-editing-and-inline-editing-mixed-together/) which is a great explanation by onabai, but i´m trying to also set a template for the temporary popup and i can´t make it work:

```
$(".k-grid-popup", grid.element).on("click", function () {
    // Temporarily set editable to "popup"
    grid.options.editable = "popup";
    // Insert row
    grid.addRow();
    // Revert editable to inline
    grid.options.editable = "inline";
});
```

How do you set the template of the popup?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

While you can access the grid options directly, any change to the options should be made using the [setOptions](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setOptions) method.  This function will notify the grid of any options change and it will be able to make all the internal change the handle the event according the the new options.

```
$(".k-grid-popup", grid.element).on("click", function () {
    grid.setOptions({editable: "popup"});
    grid.addRow();
    grid.setOptions({editable: "inline"});
});
```

I don't have any working example of your code so I can't tell if you need to change something else in your code.

Comment: What i did was this to set a template for that popup: grid.setOptions({editable: "popup",template:kendo.template($("#customPopup").html())}); but it didn´t work